# Read files recursively from github repos

Tags: r, git, github

I have some files in github that I would like to read recursively in R. So If I do this, I get list of all files.

```
library(httr)
req <- req <- GET("https://api.github.com/repos/jakevdp/data-USstates/git/trees/master?recursive=1")
stop_for_status(req)
all.files <- unlist(lapply(content(req)$tree, "["), use.names = F)
file.names.only <- unlist(lapply(content(req)$tree, "[", "path"), use.names = F)
```

Which is not what I actually wanted. I would like to be able to read these from the repository itself just like using `list.files` locally. How can we make this work? Or, at least, get list of full url to each file in the repository that can be read locally.

Say, from this repository: `https://github.com/jakevdp/data-USstates`

Comment: @Mako212 That will do. Thanks

Comment: @Mako212 Mind turning your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this fairly simply with the `rvest` library. We select the links by using the `.js-navigation-open` html node, and then pull the `href` values from the links. We get a couple of empty strings with that, and `.[. != ""]` removes those.

```
library(rvest) 

fileList <- read_html("https://github.com/jakevdp/data-USstates") %>% 
  html_nodes(".js-navigation-open") %>% 
  html_attr("href") %>%
  .[. != ""] # remove empty elements

 [1] "/jakevdp/data-USstates/blob/master/README.md"            "/jakevdp/data-USstates/blob/master/state-abbrevs.csv"   
 [3] "/jakevdp/data-USstates/blob/master/state-areas.csv"      "/jakevdp/data-USstates/blob/master/state-population.csv"
```